# Final do ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, .net, vb.net

Gostaria de saber se existe uma certa tendência em o ASP.NET WebForms se  "aposentar", ficando apenas o ASP.NET MVC, pois de acordo com este artigo a resposta seria sim. O autor do artigo (Ramon Durães) pelo menos ao meu ver é um grande conhecedor da tecnologia .NET.

A dúvida foi gerada diante da possibilidade de utilização de ASP.NET WebForms  em um novo projeto, digamos de tamanho médio.

Artigo:
[Aposentadoria do ASP.NET WebForms](http://www.ramonduraes.net/2014/10/20/o-fim-do-asp-net-webforms/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, Anderson.

A tendência realmente é essa, porém isso não quer dizer que o suporte aos Web Forms será removido do Visual Studio, pelo menos não ainda. Inclusive o Web Forms teve atualizações na nova versão do ASP.NET (Web Forms 4.6), mas o foco dos esforços será sim o MVC. O Web Forms não irá acompanhar todas as novidades da plataforma ASP.NET e logo se tornará obsoleto.

Claro que para projetos pequenos e rápidos, com pouca manutenção, eu não vejo problemas em usar Web Forms (apesar de que eu hoje já não faria mais isso), porém considerando o cenário atual da web e do mercado, não é mais viável investir em Web Forms para novos projetos grandes (na verdade, projetos pequenos podem crescer também, não é mesmo?).

A menos que você tenha um bom motivo para usar Web Forms em seu novo projeto, lhe aconselho partir para o MVC, que é uma plataforma atual, está em constante atualização e nos fornece diversos recursos para desenvolver os mais variados tipos de aplicação. O MVC também permite investir mais em front-end, garantindo uma interface final mais agradável para o cliente e mais flexível e gerenciável para o programador.

Bem, em resumo é isso. Abraço.

Answer (score 2):

Cara, afirmar assim que será o fim, não acho que deveria, até porque a escolha de qual plataforma seguir, vai depender exclusivamente do Arquiteto e/ou GerProj. Agora, quanto a tendência, acho que o MVC veio forte e tarde, pois linguagem como Java, já "embutia" o MVC em quase tudo, há bastante tempo. Gosto do MVC. Agora dizer que a MicroSoft vai obrigar as pessoas a optarem sempre para o MVC, não acho que ela faria isso. Acho que a MS permitirá por muito tempo ainda, que os arquitetos e gerproj, escolha qual caminho a seguir e ela continuará a fornecer esses dois caminhos, assim acho.