# ASP.NET Web Forms ou MVC. Qual o Melhor e o Mais rápido?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho Grande Conhecimento em WebForm, mais vejo bastante crescimento no MVC.
O WebForm será extinto ? O MVC é melhor que o WebForm.

Comment: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/95212/when-to-favor-asp-net-webforms-over-mvc

Comment: Relacionadas: [Os paradigmas MVC e Webforms (com code-behind) são mutuamente excludentes?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131614/91) e [Final do ASP.NET WebForms?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/72411/91)

Comment: Isso pode ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111209/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/49094/101

Comment: O WebForms é considerada tecnologia legada. Não digo que não deve usá-lo mais, porém saiba que não haverá mias evolução importante nele. Na verdade o ASP.Net MVC também já é praticamente legado. Se quer partir para algo mais moderno o caminho é o ASP.Net Core (antigamente chamado de ASP.Net 5 ou ASP.Net MVC 6, veja http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52158/101). Tem algo sobre o .Net Core como um todo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Difícil falar assim, é melhor..

Quando tratamos com tipos de programação, muito vai depender do seu conhecimento em programar, e claro na linguagem em questão.

**O Web Forms.**

Como de conhecimento geral, é o tal pega e arrasta.

Tem sua importância, e claro, é mais simples de ser utilizado, porém o código por trás geralmente acaba tendo um código sujo, que dependendo da sua aplicação pode trazer dificuldades.

Hoje em dia, vem caindo no esquecimento, se assim posso dizer, ou melhor, desuso, apesar da Microsoft dizer que não será descontinuado, ele não faz parte do `ASP.NET 5`, então fica de fora de alguns recursos que essa nova versão pode trazer.

**O MVC**

A sigla MVC vem de Model, View e Controller, uma arquitetura que já existe a bastante tempo, é mais complexa sim, que o `WebForms` mas possibilita um código mais limpo, por dar ferramentas que englobam todo o aplicativo, e é claro, esse é o time que entra em jogo na versão ASP.NET 5

- **Modelos**. Os objetos de modelo são as partes do aplicativo que implementam a lógica para o domínio de dados do aplicativo. Muitas vezes, os objetos de modelo recuperam e armazenam o estado do modelo em um banco de dados. Por exemplo, um objeto Product pode recuperar informações de um banco de dados, operar nele e, em seguida, gravar informações atualizadas de volta em uma tabela de Produtos em um banco de dados do SQL Server. Em aplicativos pequenos, o modelo, muitas vezes, é uma separação conceitual em vez de física. Por exemplo, se o aplicativo apenas ler um conjunto de dados e enviá-lo para exibição, o aplicativo não terá uma camada de modelo físico nem classes associadas. Nesse caso, o conjunto de dados assume a função de um objeto de modelo.
- **Exibições.** As exibições são os componentes que exibem a interface do usuário (IU) do aplicativo. Normalmente, esta IU é criada a partir dos dados do modelo. Um exemplo seria uma exibição de edição de uma tabela de Produtos que mostra caixas de texto, listas suspensas e caixas de seleção com base no estado atual de um objeto Product.
- **Controladores**. Os controladores são os componentes que lidam com a interação do usuário, trabalham com o modelo e, finalmente, selecionam uma exibição de renderização que mostra essa IU. Em um aplicativo MVC, a exibição só mostra informações; o controlador manipula e responde à entrada e à interação do usuário. Por exemplo, o controlador manipula valores da cadeia de consulta e passa esses valores ao modelo, que por sua vez pode usar estes valores para consultar o banco de dados.

**Conclusão**

Se você é um programador que esta começando agora, ou seja, esta estudando para aprender, recomendaria o `MVC`, por uma simples e obvia logica, é a arquitetura do momento, e onde os caras estão apostando as fichas, ou seja, vem por ai muita atualização.

Mas se você e um programador experiente, já familiarizado com o `WebForms`, te pergunto, não está na hora de se atualizar?

Referencias:

[Visão geral do ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd381412(v=vs.108).aspx)

[Principais mudanças no ASP.NET 5 e MVC](http://blog.caelum.com.br/principais-mudancas-no-asp-net-5-e-mvc-6/)

Comment: Obrigado Pela Informação.

Comment: @AndersondeFreitasMigloranza não é necessário formalidade, utilize os campos de cometários para tirar duvidas e etc. Veja nossa central de ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Existem várias diferenças entre as tecnologias mencionadas. O MVC é um padrao antigo, mas o ASP.NET MVC é a evoluçao natural do ASP.NET.

Se voce analisar pelo lado do designer, o Asp.NET MVC é muito mais compativel com os dispositivos que temos hoje. Ele gera um HTML puro, bem diferente do Webforms onde é injetado muito html para suporte. O MVC nao possui postback e é RestFull.

Eu diria que sim, que MVC é mais rápido que o WebForms.

Deixo aqui um artigo do Israel Aece sobre este assunto:
[COMPARATIVO: MVC VS. WEBFORMS](https://israelaece.com/2008/01/10/comparativo-mvc-vs-webforms/)

Att

William

Comment: Obrigado pela Informação.

Answer (score 1):

De um lado temos anos de experiência e evolução, com uma vasta quantidade de ferramentas que aumentam consideravelmente a produtividade, tornando o desenvolvimento fácil e rápido nos WebForms.

Já do outro lado temos um framework que visa uma divisão mais organizada, tornando mais fácil o gerenciamento de aplicações grandes e complexas, permitindo melhor suporte ao desenvolvimento orientado a testes e dando ao desenvolvedor o total controle do comportamento da aplicação.

**Acredito que a resposta mais adequada para a pergunta lá de cima seja:** as duas! Vai depender muito da aplicação que será desenvolvida, dos recursos envolvidos, do prazo, e porque não, do preço. Sabendo das diferenças, dos benefícios e empecilhos de cada uma das arquiteturas, a resposta ficará clara para cada situação.

REf: http://www.devmedia.com.br/artigo-net-magazine-65-asp-net-webforms-x-mvc/13896

Comment: Obrigado pela Informação.